# Kotlin - Composition of multiples IO

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I'm new to Kotlin's Arrow Framework and I have a couple of questions:

Lets suppose

```kotlin
fun getUser(id: Int): IO<Option<User>>
fun getCards(user: User): IO<List<Card>>


fun getUserAndCards(id: Int): IO<Option<Pair<User, List<Card>>>> = IO.fx {
    when (val user = !userRepository.get(id)) {
        is None -> None
        is Some -> {
            val cards = !cardRepository.get(user.t.id)
            Some(Pair(user.t, cards))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in an "arrow stylish" manner?

I manage to get:

```kotlin
fun getUserAndCards(id: Int): IO<Option<Pair<User, List<Card>>>> = IO.fx {
    userRepository.get(id).bind().map { user ->
        val cards = cardRepository.get(user.id).bind()
        Pair(user, cards)
    }
}
```

But I obtain `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` in the second `bind()`.

**EDIT**:
I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039277/how-to-use-io-compositions-in-arrow-kt-within-sync-context) with the same question. In the answer provided, it says *The problem is that the left/none option isn't covered.* But IT IS covered, when applying `map` to a `None` it is expected to obtain a `None`.

Answer (score 2):

With the new 0.11.0 release coming up soon, the most idiomatic way would be to use Arrow Fx Coroutines.

Rewriting the example to Arrow Fx Coroutines would be:

```
suspend fun getUser(id: Int): Option<User>
suspend fun getCards(user: User): List<Card>


suspend fun getUserAndCards(id: Int): Option<Pair<User, List<Card>>> =
  option {
    val user = !userRepository.get(id)
    val cards = !cardRepository.get(user.t.id)
    Pair(user.t, cards)
  }
```

Where you can now rely on a `option { }` DSL to extract the values from `Option`.

> The problem is that the left/none option isn't covered. But IT IS covered, when applying map to a None it is expected to obtain a None.

You're correct that it's covered, but `!` is a suspending function, and `map` is currently not inlined so you're not allowed to call `!` inside. In the `0.11.0` release the operators from the data types in Arrow-Core are `inline`, to improve support for `suspend` functions and this would solve the `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` error.

In other functional languages such as Haskell monad transformers are often used (`OptionT`), but in Kotlin using `suspend` is a much better fit which also has quite some performance benefits over wrapping monad transfomers.

As mentioned in the other post, you can also always use `traverse` or `sequence` to turn two containers around. `Option<IO<User>> -> IO<Option<User>>`

Comment: Looking forward to Arrow 0.11 :)